# Give user admin rights on a single server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows

Is it possible to give a Windows Domain User account administrator rights on a single server? We have a vendor installing software and they are requiring domain administrator access to the machine.

Comment: `"and they are requiring domain administrator access to the machine"` - I assume that's a typo and the word "domain" should not be in there?

Comment: The answer has already been given and accepted. Still, shouldn't the ideal answer be 'kick the form which produced the software and tell them to come out of the stone ages?'. Most properly coded software does not need admin rights.  /petpeeve.

Comment: @Hennes: you typically need admin rights to do the installation, unless the application is only going to run when a particular user is logged on, which is unlikely for server software.

Comment: I agree. *During installation*.  The server administrator installs the software (after logging in with an account with admin priveleges). But the regular user account should not need it just to use the software.  And yes, I know that this often fails to work. E.g. when software opens the registry without specifying that it want to READ (the default is RW).

Comment: @Hennes: certainly, but what does that have to do with this question?  The people asking for admin access were installing the software, not using it.

Comment: If you want to give a single domain user admin rights so that that domain user can install the software then yes. You are correct.  If you have a vendor stating that they need [domain] admin rights just to use a program (which is the way I read it) then things are different.

Comment: @Hennes: the OP specifically described the situation as a "vendor installing software" not as a "vendor using software".  I interpret that as meaning that the vendor sent a technician to do the software installation, and said technician needed admin access.  YMMV.

Comment: All to often, developers write their code on a PC with the full development product suite installed (e.g.: Visual Studio with all options, and all .NET versions), and write their code signed in as a local admin.  They then try to pass their shoddy security model off as "this is how it has to be".  Sat through numerous face-to-face and teleconference sessions with external developers explaining (for example) that the IUSR_xxxxxxx user cannot be a local admin.  Like Hennes said, stone ages.  Developers should focus a little less on function, and a little more on security. </rant>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a member server, you can add them to local administrator group:

- (2003) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739265%28v=WS.10%29.aspx
- (2008) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772524.aspx

This won't work if it's a domain controller though -- there are no local accounts. You'd need to run the installer as a different user or temporarily elevate their account.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, add them to the local administrators group on the server. You can do this from the command-lind as follows:

`net localgroup administrators /add domain\user`

You can also do this from the Users and Groups MMC snap-in.